# Getting exception when accessing outlook through Redemption COM

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

We are accessing outlook through redemption DLL in c#.net. We are using various services like: importing contacts, calendar integration etc.  Sometime we are getting exception from redemption COM like:

```
   The file abc.ost is in use and cannot be accessed.
   'MyApplication' exited without properly closing your Outlook data file
```

Could somebody help us to identify the root cause of this issue?

Exception details are mentioned below:

Exception1:

> OutlookServices.OutlookService -
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040119): Error in
>   IMAPISession.OpenEntry: MAPI_E_EXTENDED_ERROR
>
> Error: 'MyApplication' exited without properly closing your Outlook
>   data file
>   'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\abc@org.com.ost'.
>   'MyApplication' must be restarted. If this error message recurs,
>   contact support for 'MyApplication' for assistance.
>
> at Interop.Redemption.IRDOSession.GetMessageFromID(String
>   EntryIDMessage, Object EntryIDStore, Object Flags)

---

Exception2:

> OutlookService - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x8004011D): Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore:
>   MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER
>
> Error: The file
>   C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\abc@sigmacare.com -
>   abc.ost is in use and cannot be accessed. Close any application that
>   is using this file, and then try again. You might need to restart your
>   computer.
>
> at Interop.Redemption.IRDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders
>   FolderType)

Comment: Redemption is a proprietary commercial software. I'd recommend contacting the Redemption developer at http://dimastr.com/redemption/contact.htm instead.

Comment: This question is tagged as "outlook-redemption". It is perfectly fine to ask Redemption questions here.

Comment: I wonder if another application might be running that is holding open the OST file? I found that Skype (formerly Lync) for business was holding the OST open. I closed lync and then the error stopped happening. I should say I got the error as shown in Exception1 above from the MSOutlook client after it had terminated abnormally... I'm not using redemption.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure your application was terminated gracefully? Do you release Redemption objects as soon as you are done with them?
2. Are both your app and Outlook running in the same security context? Is either app running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator)? Normally, OST files can be shared between different processes (e.g. outlook and your process) as long as the security contexts are the same.